# Tool to track call/dataflow graph

Tags: android, dataflow

Me and my teammates often hit regression bugs (someone changes another's code and causes bugs due to lack of knowledge about that piece of code). Of course we have a set of test, but doesn't catch all bugs. So I'm thinking about using a data map, similar to the caller/callee graph when you generate java docs by tool. However, we are deving Android, and in most cases the callers are just broadcasters, and the callee are catchers. It's not that direct, making it impossible to auto-generate such graph (to my knowledge).

So I'm thinking of using some kind of online board to (semi-) manually input the flows, and share in the team. Any tip?

Thanks